# How can I find a path for process with *32 in it's name using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am using a batch file to try and find a process named "you.exe". But in task manager the name is "you.exe *32". How can I find it's path?
I tried the script:

```
for %%I in (PROCESS-NAME.exe *32) do set "ExPath=%%~$PATH:I"
echo %ExPath%
```

But for some reason it doesn't work on processes that has *32 in their name.
it only works on processes with normal names like "you.exe"

**How can I find the path for those processes?**
I am using windows 7

Also what do I do in case I have more than 1 process with the same name ?
.
.
I will give you an example:  [image]

**As suggested by one of the users in the answers, I am using this batch file to search:**

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "process=issch.exe"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`wmic process where "name='%process%'"
                               get executablepath /value 2^>nul ^| findstr 
^=`) do (
  set %%p
)

if defined executablePath (
   echo %executablePath%
 )^
else (
  echo Unable to find process: %process%
)

PAUSE
```

when I try to search for process: `issch.exe` thats marked in the picture it gives me nothing. **Not even the not found message**
But when I try to search for a different name: `ipoint.exe` it works fine.
Or if I try to search for `issch.exe *32`  i get a **not found message**.

So my guess is that it finds the process `issch.exe` but for some reason it can't process its' values.
 I get the same "error" for every process that has ***32** in it's name.

How can I search for processes with *32 in their names, and get their path?

Comment: How about you edit your question with the exact content of the script you are saying doesn't work and explain what about it doesn't work. _`PROCESS-NAME.exe` does not have `*32` in it's name_. Do you know what this does, `%%~$PATH:I`?

Comment: You could just put quotes around the filename in the for construct? Without seeing your code, there's not much more to suggest at present.

Comment: Where do you get the process name from? If you are reading the output of the `tasklist` command, that doesn't put *32 after the process name. It can't be Task Manager as that's a graphical interface, so your batch file won't be able to read that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `wmic` command to retrieve the executable path of a process. The following script looks for all the processes with the name `PROCESS-NAME.exe` and sets the variable `executablePath` to the path of the processes that were found.

The problem with this approach is that for every single match, the variable `executablePath` will be overwritten. The `executablePath` variable will be set to the last match found.

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "process=PROCESS-NAME.exe"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`wmic process where "name='%process%'"
                                   get executablepath /value 2^>nul ^| findstr ^=`) do (
  set %%p
)

if defined executablePath (
  echo %executablePath%
)^
else (
  echo Unable to find process: %process%
)
```

Another approach is to check if the variable `exePath` is already defined before setting its value. This way the `exePath` variable will be set to the first match found.

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "process=PROCESS-NAME.exe"

for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%p in (`wmic process where "name='%process%'"
                                          get executablepath 2^>nul`) do (
  if not defined exePath (
    set "exePath=%%p"
  )
)

if not "%exePath%" == "" (
  echo %exePath%
)^
else (
  echo Unable to find process: %process%
)
```

In order to save the executable paths of every single process, the retrieved values will have to be stored in separate variables. Keep in mind that if the process that you are looking for is executed multiple times from the same location, all the retrieved values are the same as well and you will need another way to differentiate one process from another. Depending on your situation, there might be a way to do this by comparing some of the other properties from the `Win32_Process` class.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "processName=PROCESS-NAME.exe"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`wmic process where "name='%processName%'"
                                   get executablepath /value 2^>nul ^| findstr ^=`) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set process[!count!].%%p
)

if not defined process[%count%].executablePath (
  echo Unable to find process: %processName%
  exit /b
)

for /l %%c in (1, 1, %count%) do (
  echo !process[%%c].executablePath!
)
```